# I am having an error in SQLite statement ON DELETE CASCADE statement in my quiz app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, syntax-error, android-sqlite

Below is the code which in which there is an error the app contains thousands of line of code so I am putting only the statement which is having a syntax error **please see the bracket inserted on delete cascade statement**  SQLite statement ON DELETE CASCADE and how can I remove this error Any help is appreciated.

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;

        final String SQL_CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                ChaptersTable.TABLE_NAME + "( " +
                ChaptersTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                ChaptersTable.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " +
                ")";
        final String SQL_CREATE_SUBJECTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                SubjectsTable.TABLE_NAME + "( " +
                SubjectsTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                SubjectsTable.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT " +
                ")";


        final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                QuestionsTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT, " +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT, " +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT, " +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT, " +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR + " INTEGER, " +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY + " TEXT, " +
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_SUBJECT_ID+ " INTEGER, " +
                "FOREIGN KEY(" + QuestionsTable.COLUMN_SUBJECT_ID+ ") REFERENCES " +
                SubjectsTable.TABLE_NAME + "(" + SubjectsTable._ID + ")" + "ON DELETE CASCADE" /*(Here im having error)*/
+
                QuestionsTable.COLUMN_CHAPTER_ID + " INTEGER, " +
                "FOREIGN KEY(" + QuestionsTable.COLUMN_CHAPTER_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
                ChaptersTable.TABLE_NAME + "(" + ChaptersTable._ID + ")" + "ON DELETE CASCADE" +
                ")";

        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_SUBJECTS_TABLE);
        fillCategoriesTable();
        fillQuestionsTable();
        fillSubjectsTable();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ChaptersTable.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SubjectsTable.TABLE_NAME);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is to define the foreign keys where you define the column itself and not later:

```
final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
        QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
        QuestionsTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR + " INTEGER, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY + " TEXT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_SUBJECT_ID+ " INTEGER " + "REFERENCES " +
        SubjectsTable.TABLE_NAME + "(" + SubjectsTable._ID + ") " + "ON DELETE CASCADE," +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_CHAPTER_ID + " INTEGER " + "REFERENCES " +
        ChaptersTable.TABLE_NAME + "(" + ChaptersTable._ID + ") " + "ON DELETE CASCADE" +
        ")";
```

or all the foreign keys at the end of the statement:

```
final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
        QuestionsTable.TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
        QuestionsTable._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_QUESTION + " TEXT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION1 + " TEXT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION2 + " TEXT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_OPTION3 + " TEXT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_ANSWER_NR + " INTEGER, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_DIFFICULTY + " TEXT, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_SUBJECT_ID+ " INTEGER, " +
        QuestionsTable.COLUMN_CHAPTER_ID + " INTEGER, " +
        "FOREIGN KEY(" + QuestionsTable.COLUMN_SUBJECT_ID+ ") REFERENCES " +
        SubjectsTable.TABLE_NAME + "(" + SubjectsTable._ID + ") " + "ON DELETE CASCADE," +
        "FOREIGN KEY(" + QuestionsTable.COLUMN_CHAPTER_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
        ChaptersTable.TABLE_NAME + "(" + ChaptersTable._ID + ") " + "ON DELETE CASCADE" +//here must come '+' to remove syntax errors 
        ")";
```

Comment: Thanks @forpas you are superb

Comment: I have edited your answer below one code was absolutely correct but above one must contain '+' before ")" Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Thanks again @forpas